# Change Outlook "Mark As Read" Behavior

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Can someone describe to me, step by step, what I would need to do in order to change the default Outlook "Mark as Read" behavior?

Default Behavior: Outlook marks a message as read when It has appeared in the viewing pane and I move to another message.

Desired Behavior: Outlook marks a message as read as soon as it appears in the viewing pane.

Comment: +1, I was just about to ask the same question. Can anyone tell why the default behavior is the way it is. I just can't find a use case where this is the desired behavior.

Comment: @Laserallan: I have forwarded your question to the [people who know about these things](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/94383/42368).

Answer (score 257):

It took me a few minutes to figure it out in Outlook 2010 and Outlook 2016 - once you get to the Reading Pane options, it's the same as squillman's answer.

1. Go to **File** → **Options** → **Advanced**.
2. In the **Outlook panes** section, click **Reading Pane...**

   [image: The Outlook Options dialog]
3. Check **Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane** and set an interval in seconds before it kicks in.

   [image: The Reading Pane dialog]

Note: In Outlook 2016, the same dialog is also available in the ribbon under **View → Reading Pane → Options...**.

Comment: The wait interval can be set to zero seconds.

Comment: Setting to 0 seconds results in instantaneous marking as read, as opposed some other settings configurators where 0 means the setting is ignored.

Answer (score 43):

For Outlook 2007:

1. Go to Tools | Options and click the Other tab
2. Click the Reading Pane... button under Outlook Panes
3. Put a check the **Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane** and set an interval in seconds before it kicks in.

It's the same for Outlook 2003, except that in step 2 the section on the Other tab is called "Reading Pane" instead of "Outlook Panes".

Answer (score 7):

In Outlook for Mac (OS X) version 15 (2016)

Select **Menu Bar -> Outlook -> Preferences -> Reading ->** select **Mark mail as read when viewed in the reading pane**

Answer (score 5):

In MS Outlook Web App for Office 365:

- Settings | Mail | Mark as read
- Mark displayed items as read as soon as they are selected
- Save

This behavior is similar to the one described by @Keyslinger and @Paul in comments above. Added as an answer to OP for those who were searching for the help with the Outlook web application, as I was.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Web applications are off-topic, and this post duplicates existing suggestions, so at best, it should be posted as supplemental information in a comment.  Answers are reserved for solutions to what was asked in the question, and each answer is intended to provide a substantively different solution than those already contributed.  Comments require a little more rep.

Answer (score 3):

[image: reading pane]

In Outlook 2016 (I assume it is the same for earlier versions), un-checking both "Mark item" options will leave the message as unread until you manually mark it as read or take some other kind of action.  This is useful if you want to keep messages unread until you reply.

I wanted to be able to set up individual mail folders with different reading pane options and could never figure it out.  In the end, it's really just as easy to set up a shortcut key in Quick Steps to mark something as "read" and configure your reading pane options as shown.  This gives you more control IMO.

Comment: For me all those are disabled, so I can uncheck only last one

Answer (score -1):

I was confused that the option reading **Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane** wouldn't allow for it to simply *Mark items as read when viewed in the Reading Pane* without specifying a delay (setting 0 disables the option) — it turns out that selecting **Mark item as read when selection changes** has the desired affect.

Comment: -1 Selecting **Mark item as read when selection changes** marks the message as read only when you switch messages. This is the default option the OP is trying to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

just unclick all of the boxes in the Reading Pane Options and it will only show up as read when you double click to open the email.

Comment: OP has asked for details your answer is like a comment

Answer (score -2):

I was able to create a Quick Step. if you have the latest version of Outlook (Exchange)
Home Tab-> Quick Steps-> Pull Down Menu-> New Quick Step-> Move to Folder-> Name as Desired -> Choose Folder (Deleted) -> Ensure "Mark as Read" is selected

Comment: This does not answer the original question.