# Completely disable automatic "Mark as read" in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I already have turned off automatic "Mark as read" for the Reading Pane (as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100333/change-outlook-mark-as-read-behavior)). But Outlook still sometimes marks mails as read as part of various other actions, e.g. forwarding or replying to a mail.

Is there a way to completely disable any and all automatic "Mark as read"? I want to exclusively control the read state manually.

Comment: I think that that is the default behaviour and you are not able to change it. The mail will be marked as read if you 1. open it 2. forward it 3. reply to it   - all of those make sense.