# Outlook marking emails as read without me opening them

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a problem with my Outlook inbox. I receive emails through IMAP and within an hour they are automatically marked as read even though I never opened them. This does not happen when I use Thunderbird or GMail with similar settings.

Has anyone experienced this behaviour and know how to correct it? It is quite frustrating to not know which emails have been read or not.

(I hope this is an appropriate question, I found a similar one here: [Change Outlook "Mark As Read" Behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/100333/change-outlook-mark-as-read-behavior)).

Comment: IMAP. This means that all email is linked across all your email platforms; phone, work pc, home pc, online anywhere. If you open your mail in your phone then all your mail anywhere (to include Outlook) will be shown as read. Another thing to note is if anyone else is checking your mail...

Comment: No one else should be checking my mail, though that is one of my concerns. I do not remember setting up my account anywhere else but it is an old account who knows. Do you suggest changing the password?

Comment: That would be a good thing to troubleshoot. Then if that fixes it then at least you can check that off your list.