# Keep as Unread when open/ double click email on outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-outlook-2016

I would like to keep the Read/ Unread Status while I open/ double-click the e-mail on outlook. Unfortunately, It seems that there is not exist any default setting/ option to define the function.
For the current status, when I double-click the unread mail, It would change the unread status to read status. Is there any approach/ method that could modify this setting? Many thanks for any feedback in advance.

Remark:
I have googled a few pieces of information, but it focuses on [changing the setting for appearing in the viewing pane and moving to another message.](https://superuser.com/questions/100333/change-outlook-mark-as-read-behavior) It is out of scope for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Once you read an email, it is "read".  Natively that is the way Outlook works (and has worked for many years).

If you really need to read an email and then show it as "not read" you have to change the email status by right clicking and changing it to "unread" .

I use the "read" status to know I have looked at an email. If I file it before reading into its regular folder, it will remain unread in the folder until I action it.

Comment: I have a recollection of a related [x] -mark in the settings, I can't currently recollect the exact function, text and meaning of it though. *(No Outlook to check)*

Comment: I have Outlook 2002 here and all versions forward to Outlook 365 and the functionality of "Read" and "Unread" is the same basic functionality all that way (time).

Comment: Agree with John, we could only change the status manually once we double-click to open the messages. And, if you only need to perform it on the specific messages, it's suggested to create a rule to move a copy of your message to other folder, so that you could read it in a specific folder and it wouldn't affect the status in other folder.

Comment: Do you still have any question about it? If not, it's suggested to mark the helpful post to answer.